# Internet Explorer Cannot Open the Internet Site Operation Aborted, how to fix this error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

This code giving error in IE

### Internet Explorer Cannot Open the Internet Site Operation Aborted, how to fix this error?

```
var tip = "<p>Most computers will open PDF documents ";
tip += "automatically, but you may";
tip += "need to download <a title='Link to Adobe website-opens in a new window'";
tip +=" href='http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/readstep2.html'  
               target='_blank'>Adobe Reader</a>.</p>";

$(document).ready(function(){

    //IF NUMBER OF PDF LINKS IS MORE THAN ZERO INSIDE DIV WITH ID maincontent
    //THEN THIS WILL PUT TIP PARAGRAPH AS LAST CHILD OF DIV
    if($("div#maincontent a[href*='/pdf']").length>0){
    $("div#maincontent").children(":last-child").after(tip);
    }
});
```

See this page in IE : http://jsbin.com/oliho4

Comment: When does the error occur? What does the error message exactly say?

Comment: I can't see the part '$(document).ready(function()' in code. Maybe that's the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me it seems obvious that you try to modify some element before the page has finished loading. At least that's exactly what you do on your demo page. You don't wrap the code in `$(document).ready()` as you did in the question

Try this demo-site instead http://jsbin.com/ivuqa which correctly wraps the relevant lines in `ready()`

---

Additionally there might be some problems when using XHTML. In that case just wrap the offending javascript part like this. (CDATA to satisfy the XML validation, javascript multiline comment to hide the the cdata from browser which don't understand it and thus would fail to run the javascript.

```
/* <![CDATA[ */
    var tip = "<p>Most computers will open PDF documents automatically, but you may need to download <a title='Link to Adobe website-opens in a new window'";
    tip +=" href='http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/readstep2.html' target='_blank'>Adobe Reader</a>.</p>";
/* ]]> */
```

Comment: thx error is gone now but this page have many W3c validation errors http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fjsbin.com%2Fekapi3

Comment: OK. and i think if i attach this code via external js then also validation problem can be solved.

Comment: you were right CDATA did the trick http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fjsbin.com%2Fiveki&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&verbose=1&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.654

Comment: @jitter - I neverunderstood properlyuse of CDATA but from my this question and ur answer egading validation Now i know understand what is the use of CDATA hanks

Answer (score 0):

Is it the infamous alert that returns a blank page in IE?

It's a known and [documented](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2009/09/03/preventing-operation-aborted-scenarios.aspx) IE issue.

This error usually occurs when you're trying to modify a DOM element before the page finished loading.

Try moving your script at the bottom of the page.

Since you're using document ready, I don't think this causes the problem. Maybe is it because of another script on your page?

EDIT:

You can also try to fire your function on the body's `onload` attribute. I just read this [here](http://talk.cmyweb.net/2008/01/26/ieoperation-aborted-solution/).

EDIT 2: I didn't see your link. Jitter is right, you're not using jQuery's `$(document).ready()`

Answer (score 0):

Script on this page may be useful:
http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2009/09/03/preventing-operation-aborted-scenarios.aspx